# How to set cachecolorhint to a class that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter

Tags: android

Hi I have created Expandible list view using BaseExpandableListAdapter. If i scroll the list then I found the default cache color as black but my background colour of list is white. I want to set cachecolour as white.

How to set cachecolorhint to a class that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter in android

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In layout XML you can use `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"` in the list view to which Adapter is assigned. otherwise programmatic you can use setCacheColor() method where you have to pass the color to avoid cache color while fast scrolling in list view.

Thanks
Deepak